# My Collision With My Platform Images Problem How To Fix?

Tags: python, pygame

the problem is that when I collide with my platform it seems to put me way higher then the [platform](https://gyazo.com/29cc50b915813ecd91dcf805ebc6e2c9) it does this for all my platforms and idk why

my collision for platform

```py
        for enemy in enemies:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.y = enemy.rect.top - playerman.height + 1
                if playerman.rect.right > enemy.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < enemy.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = enemy.rect.left - player.width
                if playerman.rect.left < enemy.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > enemy.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = enemy.rect.right
```

my full code

```py
# import module
import pygame
pygame.init()

# window
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,470))
pygame.display.set_caption("YELOLL")

background = pygame.image.load("bg.jpg")
left_image = pygame.image.load("Sprite-0003.png")
right_image = pygame.image.load("Sprite-0002.png")
Right_Coins = pygame.image.load("Coin.png")
platforms = pygame.image.load("rat.png")

def Redraw():
    window.blit(background, (0,0))
# draw the player
class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.fall = 0
        self.left_image = False
        self.right_image = False
        self.speed = 5
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.left_image = pygame.image.load("Sprite-0002.png")
        self.right_image = pygame.image.load("Sprite-0003.png")
        self.left_image = pygame.transform.scale(self.left_image,(self.left_image.get_width()//1,self.left_image.get_height()//1))
        self.right_image = pygame.transform.scale(self.right_image,(self.right_image.get_width()//1,self.right_image.get_height()//1))

        ...
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,left_image.get_width(), left_image.get_height())
        self.direction = "left" #set a stating direction

    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        if self.direction == "left":
            window.blit(self.left_image,self.rect)
        else: 
            window.blit(self.right_image,self.rect)
# enemy


class enemy:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.platforms = pygame.image.load("rat.png")
        self.platforms = pygame.transform.scale(self.platforms,(self.platforms.get_width()//2,self.platforms.get_height()//2))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,platforms.get_width(), platforms.get_height())
        self.direction = "left" #set a stating direction


    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.platforms,self.rect)

# coins
class coin:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.Right_Coins = pygame.image.load("Coin.png")
        self.Right_Coins = pygame.transform.scale(self.Right_Coins,(self.Right_Coins.get_width()//2,self.Right_Coins.get_height()//2))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,Right_Coins.get_width(), Right_Coins.get_height())
        self.direction = "left" #set a stating direction


    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.Right_Coins,self.rect)
class botts:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, self.rect)

font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
score = 0
text = font.render('Score = ' + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = (100, 40)
# FPS
FPS  = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# colors
Green = (0,255,2)
white = (255,255,255)
Yellow = (248,255,0)
Blue = (0,255,201)

# define player and enemy
playerman = player(50,390,30,30, Blue)
enemy1 = enemy(180,390,150,10, Green)
enemy2 = enemy(300,290,150,10, Green)
enemy3 = enemy(70,250,150,10, Green)
enemy4 = botts(-10000,490,150000,50, white)
teleport = enemy(390,390,40,80, white)

enemies = [enemy1,enemy2,enemy3,enemy4]

# define coins
coin1 = coin(230,370,10,10, Yellow)
coin2 = coin(350,270,10,10, Yellow)
coin3 = coin(150,230,10,10, Yellow)
coin4 = coin(250,450,10,10, Yellow)

Coins_list = [coin1,coin2,coin3,coin4,teleport]


# main loop
runninggame = True
while runninggame:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runninggame = False
    Redraw()
    clock.tick(FPS)
    teleport.draw()
    window.blit(text,textRect)
    playerman.draw()
    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.draw()
    for coin in Coins_list:
        coin.draw()



    if playerman.y < 250:
        playerman.y += 1
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.y += playerman.speed
        for coin in Coins_list:
            coin.y += playerman.speed
    if playerman.y > 450:
        playerman.y -= playerman.fall
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.y -= playerman.fall
        for coin in Coins_list:
            coin.y -= playerman.fall

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()



    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerman.direction = "left"
        playerman.x -= playerman.speed
        if playerman.x < 100:
            playerman.x += playerman.speed
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy.x += playerman.speed
            for coin in Coins_list:
                coin.x += playerman.speed




    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerman.direction = "right"
        playerman.x += playerman.speed
        if playerman.x > 450:
            playerman.x -= playerman.speed
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy.x -= playerman.speed
            for coin in Coins_list:
                coin.x -= playerman.speed






    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        collide = False
        for enemy in enemies:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.y = enemy.rect.top - playerman.height + 1
                if playerman.rect.right > enemy.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < enemy.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = enemy.rect.left - player.width
                if playerman.rect.left < enemy.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > enemy.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = enemy.rect.right

            for i in range(len(Coins_list)-1,-1,-1):
                if playerman.rect.colliderect(Coins_list[i].rect):
                    del Coins_list[i]
                    score += 1
                    text = font.render('Score = ' + str(score), True,  (255,255,255))
                    textRect = text.get_rect()
                    textRect.center = (100,40)

            if playerman.rect.colliderect(teleport.rect):
                for enemy in enemies:
                    if playerman.rect.centerx:
                        playerman.x = 50
                        playerman.y = 150

        if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
            collide = True
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10
            playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height


        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
            playerman.fall = 0
    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount > 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.4
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10

    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is hidden in the class `Platform`, because `self.platforms` is not the same as `platform`.
Note `self.platforms` is scaled to its half size, thus you have to use `self.platforms` rather than `platform` when you setup the rectangle (`self.rect`):

<s>`self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,platforms.get_width(), platforms.get_height())`</s>

```py
self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y, self.platforms.get_width(), self.platforms.get_height())
```

Anyway, I recommend to get the rectangle by `get_rect()`:

```py
self.rect = self.platforms.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
```

class `Paltform`:

```py
class enemy:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.platforms = pygame.image.load("rat.png")
        self.platforms = pygame.transform.scale(self.platforms,(self.platforms.get_width()//2,self.platforms.get_height()//2))

        self.rect = self.platforms.get_rect(topleft = (x, y)) # <---

        self.direction = "left" #set a stating direction
```

If the top of the image is not *hittable*, like spread grass, the you have to shrink the hitbox by the height of the grass.
Add a method to the class  `enemy`, which returns the hitbox:

```py
class enemy:
    # [...]

    def get_hitbox(self):
        grass_height = 25
        hitboxb = self.rect
        hitboxb.top += grass_height
        return hitboxb
```

```py
class botts:
    # [...]

    def get_hitbox(self):
        return self.rect
```

Use the hit box for the collision detection:

```py
for enemy in enemies:

     enemy_hitbox = enemy.get_hitbox()

     if playerman.rect.colliderect(enemy_hitbox):
         collide = True
         playerman.y = enemy_hitbox.top - playerman.height + 1
         # [...]
```

Comment: it works good but it still seems a little higher then my platform sorry I just started with images in pygame yesterday is there a way to make it stand on the platform instead of the air

Comment: covers the whole surface didn't add any transparent borders

Comment: https://gyazo.com/2bc690f1b29c169fe579bc7afbffa41a there is a gap

Comment: so its my grass that is causing the problem because how it is spreaded apart?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/4979c040a2ca25ba570f1e658c7f65c2 Thanks that worked I + 25 I think I need to create a new class for the bottom then add the collision cause its effecting my flower making me go down

Comment: @HabibIsmail I've extended the answer.

Comment: Thanks Also Last Question because my tile for bottom is defferent I created a new class for it and and then draw it on my screen it doesnt seem to show up and making me constantly fall  [Class](https://gyazo.com/d065c1a3ed00ff7775e1a44ee4b0713d) [define class](https://gyazo.com/386a81bf798c663a45de9aead4ab7061) and then I enemy4.draw() and it wont show up on my screen for some reason  [constantly falling](https://gyazo.com/b6c9ec460d7a5f2d4496038cc76c833d)

Comment: @HabibIsmail Possibly the same issue as before, `fls_dudos.get_width()` -> `self.fls_dudos.get_width()` (same for `get_height()`)? Did you add it to `enemies`?

Comment: I don';t know why but this time I did the same thing for my [floor](https://gyazo.com/2293b09cd418ed1cf3775cfef3b31825) class and then when I add + 15  to my  [collision](https://gyazo.com/7e1155f783ee6d430390927e4ce55336)  instead of 1 it keeps lowering me instead of putting me higher on my floor platform I cant manage to figure the problem