# Level List Wont Load in Platforms Problem

Tags: python, pygame

I have created a level list where it suppose to load in more platforms BUT I don't know why it isn't loading the platforms

## it suppose to load in pp -- platforms

```
        platformGroup = pygame.sprite.Group
        platformList = []
        level = ["                            ",
        "                            ",
        "                            ",
        "     pppp          pppp             ",
        "                            ",
        "    pppp                        ",
        "                            ",
        "                ppppp            ",
        "       pppp                     ",
        "                            ",]

        for row in level:
            for col in row:
                if col == "P":
                    enemy(x,y)
                    platformGroup.add
                    platformList.append
```

my full code

```
# import module
import pygame
pygame.init()

# window
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,470))
pygame.display.set_caption("YELOLL")

background = pygame.image.load("bg.jpg")
left_image = pygame.image.load("Sprite-0003.png")
right_image = pygame.image.load("Sprite-0002.png")
Right_Coins = pygame.image.load("Coin.png")
platforms = pygame.image.load("rat.png")

def Redraw():
    window.blit(background, (0,0))
# draw the player
class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.fall = 0
        self.left_image = False
        self.right_image = False
        self.speed = 5
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.left_image = pygame.image.load("Sprite-0002.png")
        self.right_image = pygame.image.load("Sprite-0003.png")
        self.left_image = pygame.transform.scale(self.left_image,(self.left_image.get_width()//1,self.left_image.get_height()//1))
        self.right_image = pygame.transform.scale(self.right_image,(self.right_image.get_width()//1,self.right_image.get_height()//1))

        ...
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,left_image.get_width(), left_image.get_height())
        self.direction = "left" #set a stating direction

    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        if self.direction == "left":
            window.blit(self.left_image,self.rect)
        else: 
            window.blit(self.right_image,self.rect)
# enemy


class enemy:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.platforms = pygame.image.load("rat.png")
        self.platforms = pygame.transform.scale(self.platforms,(self.platforms.get_width()//2,self.platforms.get_height()//2))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,platforms.get_width(), platforms.get_height())
        self.direction = "left" #set a stating direction


    def draw(self):
        platformGroup = pygame.sprite.Group
        platformList = []
        level = ["                            ",
        "                            ",
        "                            ",
        "     pppp          pppp             ",
        "                            ",
        "    pppp                        ",
        "                            ",
        "                ppppp            ",
        "       pppp                     ",
        "                            ",]

        for row in level:
            for col in row:
                if col == "P":
                    enemy(x,y)
                    platformGroup.add
                    platformList.append
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.platforms,self.rect)

# coins
class coin:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.Right_Coins = pygame.image.load("Coin.png")
        self.Right_Coins = pygame.transform.scale(self.Right_Coins,(self.Right_Coins.get_width()//2,self.Right_Coins.get_height()//2))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,Right_Coins.get_width(), Right_Coins.get_height())
        self.direction = "left" #set a stating direction


    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.Right_Coins,self.rect)
class botts:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, self.rect)



font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
score = 0
text = font.render('Score = ' + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = (100, 40)
# FPS
FPS  = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# colors
Green = (0,255,2)
white = (255,255,255)
Yellow = (248,255,0)
Blue = (0,255,201)

# define player and enemy
playerman = player(50,390,30,30, Blue)
enemy1 = enemy(180,390,150,10, Green)
enemy2 = enemy(300,290,150,10, Green)
enemy3 = enemy(70,250,150,10, Green)
enemy4 = botts(-10000,490,150000,50, white)

enemies = [enemy1,enemy2,enemy3,enemy4]

# define coins
coin1 = coin(230,370,10,10, Yellow)
coin2 = coin(350,270,10,10, Yellow)
coin3 = coin(150,230,10,10, Yellow)
coin4 = coin(250,450,10,10, Yellow)

Coins_list = [coin1,coin2,coin3,coin4]


# main loop
runninggame = True
while runninggame:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runninggame = False




    Redraw()
    clock.tick(FPS)
    window.blit(text,textRect)
    playerman.draw()
    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.draw()
    for coin in Coins_list:
        coin.draw()




    if playerman.y < 250:
        playerman.y += 1
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.y += playerman.speed
        for coin in Coins_list:
            coin.y += playerman.speed
    if playerman.y > 450:
        playerman.y -= playerman.fall
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.y -= playerman.fall
        for coin in Coins_list:
            coin.y -= playerman.fall

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()



    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerman.direction = "left"
        playerman.x -= playerman.speed
        if playerman.x < 100:
            playerman.x += playerman.speed
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy.x += playerman.speed
            for coin in Coins_list:
                coin.x += playerman.speed




    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerman.direction = "right"
        playerman.x += playerman.speed
        if playerman.x > 450:
            playerman.x -= playerman.speed
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy.x -= playerman.speed
            for coin in Coins_list:
                coin.x -= playerman.speed






    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        collide = False
        for enemy in enemies:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.y = enemy.rect.top - playerman.height + 1
                if playerman.rect.right > enemy.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < enemy.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = enemy.rect.left - player.width
                if playerman.rect.left < enemy.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > enemy.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = enemy.rect.right

            for i in range(len(Coins_list)-1,-1,-1):
                if playerman.rect.colliderect(Coins_list[i].rect):
                    del Coins_list[i]
                    score += 1
                    text = font.render('Score = ' + str(score), True,  (255,255,255))
                    textRect = text.get_rect()
                    textRect.center = (100,40)



        if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
            collide = True
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10
            playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height


        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
            playerman.fall = 0
    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount > 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.4
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10


    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `enemie.draw` is the wrong place to do that. You have to create the level before the main application loop, instead of the line:

<s>`enemies = [enemy1,enemy2,enemy3,enemy4]`</s>

Create `enemy` objects in a nested loop (`new_enemy`) and append each new enemy to `enemies`. Don't forget to add the ground `enemy4`:

```py
enemy4 = botts(-10000,490,150000,50, white)
enemies = [enemy4]

platformGroup = pygame.sprite.Group
platformList = []
level = ["                            ",
"                            ",
"                            ",
"     pppp          pppp             ",
"                            ",
"    pppp                        ",
"                            ",
"                ppppp            ",
"       pppp                     ",
"                            ",]

for iy, row in enumerate(level):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "p":
            new_enemy = enemy(ix*10, iy*50, 10, 10, Green)
            enemies.append(new_enemy)
```

Note, character compare is case sensitive, if you use `"p"` in the level string, then you have to evaluate `col == "p"` rather than `col == "P"`.

Comment: Thanks also is there a way you could help me with the [collision](https://gyazo.com/29cc50b915813ecd91dcf805ebc6e2c9)  it seems like the collision with the tiles are a little higher then the tiles idk why.

Comment: @HabibIsmail Thank you. You're welcome. I've answered your previous question, too. [My Collision With My Platform Images Problem How To Fix? pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61754777/my-collision-with-my-platform-images-problem-how-to-fix-pygame/61755112#61755112)